# how to open a new view whilst keeping an old one visible

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have seen quite a few apps on the app store which display adverts at the top or bottom. I have managed to get adverts to work that is not the problem.

What i was wondering is how do you keep the same advert visible when you load a new view?

I am currently using the present and dismiss modal view functions to navigate through my app.

Thank you,

Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retain the advertView in a singleton class/AppDelgete (Means Keep this advert view as global and show it on each viewdidLoad) .

Answer (score 1):

You can add the view as a subview of the window. You might have to bring the view to the front. However this approach will need to observe orientation changes and rotate the view appropriately. While this is possible, such a view might make the animations feel odd.